# Need help on GCC GIMPLE

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I have been looking into GCC's GIMPLE and building a front-end.  I have been looking through the codebase, however wrapping my head around all the concepts is taking more time than I would like due to what appears to be a lack of documentation.  Are there resources online that explain how GIMPLE works?

I have found the following, where the PDF was quite informative:
http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GIMPLE

Answer (score 2):

have a look [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/GCC-Frontend-HOWTO-1.html): GCC Frontend HOWTO... 
and [here](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~uday/courses/cs715-09/gcc-gimple.pdf): from the gcc resource center, IIT Bombay.

Answer (score 1):

Some useful information on GIMPLE and GIMPLE-SSA can be found here: http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/classement/doc/A-381.pdf